# C# foreach se repite 300+ veces

Tags: c#, foreach, datagridview

soy lo que viene a ser el nivel antes de novato y es la primera vez que escribo por aquí (me ha resultado muy útil esta pagina en varias ocasiones).

Explicare para que sirve el programa que estoy escribiendo, básicamente carga una pagina HTML local con una tabla de la cual ira extrayendo varios resultados, los cuales integrara a un DataGridView.

[Imagen del programa que devuelve el error...]:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí viene el problema, estoy usando foreach y se repite la operación 300+ veces...

No entiendo, ni encuentro donde este el problema.
Podrían iluminarme?
Gracias.

[Código HTML del que intento extraer los datos]:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-width:0px;width:809pt;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:16.4pt;">
<td class="sd2f9551a" style="width:42.9pt;height:16.4pt;"></td>
<td class="s054608a3" style="height:15.7pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:70.8pt;">601</td>
<td class="s828d7148" style="height:15.7pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:106.6pt;">001834820601</td>
<td class="s828d7148" colspan="7" style="height:15.7pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:128.1pt;"></td>
<td class="s828d7148" colspan="3" style="height:15.7pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:121pt;"></td>
<td class="sf7752056" colspan="6" style="height:15.7pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:214pt;"></td>
<td class="s054608a3" style="height:15.7pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:78pt;">EMBARCADO</td>
<td class="s9a0851f4" style="width:42.9pt;height:16.4pt;"></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.7pt;">
<td class="sd2f9551a" style="width:42.9pt;height:15.7pt;"></td>
<td class="s054608a3" style="height:15pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:70.8pt;">602</td>
<td class="s828d7148" style="height:15pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:106.6pt;">001834820602</td>
<td class="s828d7148" colspan="7" style="height:15pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:128.1pt;"></td>
<td class="s828d7148" colspan="3" style="height:15pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:121pt;"></td>
<td class="sf7752056" colspan="6" style="height:15pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:214pt;"></td>
<td class="s054608a3" style="height:15pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:78pt;">EMBARCADO</td>
<td class="s9a0851f4" style="width:42.9pt;height:15.7pt;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[Fragmento del código que devuelve el error...]:

```
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tbody"))
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("//tr[(@style='height:16.4pt;') or (@style='height:15.7pt;')]"))
                {
                    DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
                    int i = 0;

                    HtmlNodeCollection cells = row.SelectNodes("td");
                    if (cells == null)
                        continue;
                    foreach (HtmlNode cell in cells)
                    {
                        r[i] = cell.InnerText;
                        i++;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(r);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Y cual seria el error?

Comment: Mas que un error, un problema donde se repite el resultado demasiadas veces (véase la imagen) donde solo debería de aparecer un solo resultado.

Comment: Y seguiste tu codigo, para ver como es el HTML y que nodos trae en cada caso? si estas haciendo un foreach, quiere deicr que hay esa cantidad de cosas en el HTML...

Comment: He estado investigando un poco y creo que el problema esta en el código HTML del cual el foreach repite 358 veces la operación. Esta es una porción del código HTML del cual quiero extraer datos (https://controlc.com/3ff5f881). Sigo investigando.

Comment: He dado con el problema sin querer. Cambiando simplemente el primer foreach de //tbody a //div[@id='MvcViewerReportPanel']. En fin, no se como no se me ocurrio antes. Gracias.